# Worldpay redirection issue - Worldpay module

Tags: prestashop

I hope somebody can help with this one.
I managed to make a test transaction through Worldpay which is executed after I click on Make payment. However, for some reason it doesn't redirect back to the website and instead we get Not found message refering to validation.php

Anybody had this issue and managed to resolve it?
Any help would be really appreciated.

Worldpay people are advising me to use a meta refresh to redirect the shopper back to the website:

Anyone would know where to put this code and how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

There may be two things wrong.

1) You have not placed correct send back url in your worldpay admin panel.

2) You dont have the validation.php in your prestashop payment module for worldpay, or the file dont have enough permissions.

Please check both of them.
Thank you

Comment: I have the same question as the above. However I am developing in ASP.NET MVC and the worldpay documentation is not clear on how I would redirect the user back to the original website with a controller and action. the documentation says use .html files, but my application required .cshtml files.